# Magnesium Bicarbonate and Ascorbic Acid Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

30 ml. Magnesium Hydroxide USP is added to 2 l. carbonated water to make magnesium bicarbonate to be used as a highly bio-absorbable Mg dietary supplement. I'm told the result is 90 mg. elemental Mg per each 4 oz. of this "Magnesium Water."

If one gram of ascorbic acid is added to a small amount of this Mg solution that has been diluted with filtered tap water, the solution becomes fizzy releasing CO2.  I didn't measure the amount of Mg solution or the amount of water, but it was approximately 2 tablespoons of dilute solution with one gram (measured) vitamin c crystals. I do understand this release of CO2 is due to the acid-base reaction.

How are the ascorbic acid and the magnesium changed in this solution? Is there still any vitamin C in the solution? What form of Mg is the result?

This is not a homework question. It's just for personal curiosity, but I only took two semesters in chemistry in the early 80's so my knowledge of the subject is very limited. Sorry if this is the wrong place for such a question. You can delete it.

Comment: It is a common reaction between an acid and a salt of a weaker acid. Have you ever tried mixing of solutions of a baking or washing soda and vinegar/citric acid ? It is the same kind of reaction.Note that neutralized ascorbic acid is much less stable, vulnerable to fast oxidation.

Answer (score 1):

Ascorbic acid reacts with bicarbonate:

$$\ce{H2Asc  + 2 HCO3-  -> Asc^2- + 2 H2O + 2 CO2 ^}$$

Ascorbate as a strong reduction agent reacts with oxygen:

$$\ce{2 Asc^2-  + O2 + 2 H2O -> 2 DHA + 4 OH-}$$

where $\ce{DHA}$ is dehydroascorbic acid.

If the ascorbic acid solution is alkalized by sodium hydroxide, the solution slowly turns yellow as the result of the oxidation progress.

Comment: What happens to the Magnesium in the reaction? Does the reaction produce Magnesium Ascorbate?

Comment: Nothing happens to magnesium. It is a bystander in the reaction. It's complementary anion has been replaced, ascorbate instead of bicarbonate.

Comment: As the general rule, ascorbic acid should avoid basic environment like bicarbonates, if it's stability is the concern.